# React Native - edit code push target / version number (in the app)

Tags: javascript, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm trying to create a small react native app that uses Code Push for updates and it works!, - however i'm a bit confused about the " target versions " - the binary version that code push uses to target which users should receive the update.

Where can i see / edit that version number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, it is `versionName` value in app > build.gradle

[image]

In iOS, it is `Version` field

[image]